# c++ How do I initialize a member array in a constructor?

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize a member array in the default constructor of a class which I've created. However, nothing I've tried has worked. I'm quite new to c++ and programming in general, and I haven't found the answer I was looking for online yet. In my .hpp file I have:

```
class thing
{
private:
    std::string array[8][8];
    
public:
    
    thing();
};
```

And in the corresponding .cpp file I have:

```
thing::thing()
{
    array =
    {
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"}
    };
//error: Array type 'std::string [8][8]' is not assignable
}
```

I've also tried the following:

```
Board::Board()
{
    std::string array[8][8] =
    {
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"}
    };
}
```

Doing it this way doesn't cause any compiler errors, but it doesn't seem to actually work. When I try to cout the elements in the array I get nothing. Is there a way to do what I want to do?

Comment: The second one creates a local variable named `array`, initializes it, and throws it away.

Comment: Use member initializer syntax: `Board::Board(): array{ {"a", "b", /*...*/ }}`

Comment: Note: arrays are second-class citizens in C++ and there is a lot you just can't do with them. Consider using `std::array` instead.

Comment: `std::string array[8][8] = { ... }`  in the constructor creates a brand new `array` local variable in the constructor which has a lifetime that ends when the constructor is finished. It does not change or alter the array class member of your class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a *constructor initializer list*, or use a *default member initializer*.

```
#include <string>

class thing {
    std::string array[8][8];

public:
    thing();
};

thing::thing()
    : array{
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
    }   
{ }

class thing2 {
    std::string array[8][8] = { 
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
    };  
};

int main() {
    thing t;
    (void)t;

    thing2 t2; 
    (void)t2;
}
```